# System.Convert does not contain a definition for "toString"

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I am trying to convert a value to a string, as far as I can tell, I have to use the method toString, of the class Convert, of the namespace System.

Here's my code:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'System.Convert' does not contain a definition for 'toString'

Source Error:


Line 101:                while (r.Read())
Line 102:                {
Line 103:                    listbox.Items.Add(new ListItem(Convert.toString(r["first_name"]), Convert.toString(r["first_name"])));
Line 104:                }
```

What am I doing wrong exactly? I'm new to C# (hence why, if you look at my profile you see like 6-7 questions, all related to C# lately!). It's really making me practice my OOP chops too!

Comment: All public methods in .NET farmework begins with capital. So toString definitelly not, maybe ToString.

Comment: Remember IntelliSense is your friend.

Answer (score 7):

C# is case sensitive try this

```
Convert.ToString()
```

Answer (score 5):

Get rid of the

```
Convert.toString(r["first_name"])
```

and change it to

```
r["first_name"].ToString()
```

Edited to rid the world of this nasty little typo :)

Comment: this answer is wrong! C# is case sensitive `r["first_name"].toString()` will throw exception

Answer (score 3):

```
Convert.ToString(myNonString); //  It's a casing issue.
```

edit: You may not want to use .ToString() because it can generate a NullReferenceException if the value you want to convert is null, and the static Convert.ToString() will always return a string (even in the case of null objects)

Answer (score 2):

Why not just call `ToString()` on the object itself:

```
new ListItem(r["first_name"].ToString())
```